# Python удерживать фокус сабпроцессе

Tags: python, subprocess

При нажатии на кнопку в приложении Python (tkinter), к примеру, открывается текстовый файл в Notepad.
Для запуска использую subprocess.Popen.

Как сделать так, чтобы после запуска Notepad при клике по окну основного приложения Python фокус передавался окну Notepad? Т.е. чтобы приложение ожидало закрытия окна Notepad

Я знаю, что subprocess.run всегда ожидает закрытия порожденного дочернего процесса, тоже самое делает Popen.wait(). Но дело в том, что при клике по родительному приложению, оно приобретает вид зависшего и в заголовке появляется фраза - "не отвечает"

Например в Windows при клике по окну родительного приложения фокус переключается на окно дочернего приложения, и граница окна дочернего приложения несколько раз мигает для привлечения внимания.

Как подобное реализовать на Python?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Тут два вопроса: чтобы окно не зависало, когда что-то запущено через subprocess, и переключение на запущенное окно. По первому вопросу - можно попробовать запускать wait в отдельном потоке. По второму - нужно как-то определять hwnd запущенного окна, при переключении фокуса на основное окно принудительно передавать фокус на запущенное.

Comment: `фокус переключается на окно дочернего приложения, и граница окна дочернего приложения несколько раз мигает для привлечения внимания.` - это вообще "само" работает если у вас окна одного приложения, и дочернее окно - модальный диалог, а тут придется вручную это поведение реализовывать.